# Change Verbage from "Linked" to "Duplicate"

Tags: discussion

I was contributing to [Do URL shorteners such as bit.ly affect SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29762/do-url-shorteners-such-as-bit-ly-affect-seo/29763#comment28672_29763) when I saw the question had been closed as a duplicate. 
At first, I couldn't figure out what the duplicate article was (In Stack Overflow a link to the duplicate article is in the "closed for duplicate" notice).
Eventually, I figured out it was on the side under a heading called "linked". I'm wondering about the verbage used here. 

 
 To me a "linked" article would be a reference from one article to another. For instance if I opened a question like "Apache error: Err X342342", I would link it to "Apache error: Err X3233" where User X gave me a solution that I implemented. In other words, a linked article is either an article where I got previous contributions form, or am drawing knowledge from (ex. User Y says (link)here(/link) to do this).

The reason the post was closed, however, is because it was a duplicate. So why not called "linked" "duplicate"? 
 Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think it may be a bug in the code that refreshes the question if someone closes it while you're answering it. If you refresh the question in your browser do you see the "possible duplicate" bit above the question text? Do you think that wasn't there before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Linked" section actually just includes all questions that link to this question or were linked from this question; the duplicate being included is incidental; since the Duplicate text includes a link, it's "linked".

The Linked section is more to keep you up to speed on related (and possible duplicate) questions.

Comment: Ok I understand now :)